# Transparent activity without one black line going across the screen?

Tags: android

I have created a real simple transparent activity by using a custom theme and color:

```
<style name="CustomTheme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/trans</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

`<color name="trans">#00000000</color>`

The only problem with this is when the activity starts one black line scrolls up the screen to the top.  I assume this is the animation of the activity starting.  Is there any way to change this so no line scrolls upwards?